# Converting 66 rows of list into dataframe python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, type-conversion

I want two columns in dataframe. names and labels.

```js
len(names),len(labels)
```

I have list of names and labels (8 values in each label) which are total 66. when i tried converting only labels, 1 row of label was picked and 8 values in that row (of label) was printed separately.

```js
for x in range(len(labels)):
  lst = (labels[x])
df = pd.DataFrame(labels[x])

df.columns =['labels']
df
```

the output it gave:

```js
    x1
0   49
1   130
2   81
3   129
4   48
5   148
6   77
7   148
```

I want these 8 values of label in 1 row (separate columns for each row is accepted)
but for some mistake its not giving me other 65 rows only 1.

I also wants names to be printed along with labels.

Answer (score 0):

The 'label' is list of list, so you can directly use
`pd.DataFrame(label)`

`pd.DataFrame(data=label,columns=name)`

here,

`df = pd.DataFrame([labels[x]])`

Adding list results in a row!!

Comment: Actually name is separate column which have each label name.

Comment: can you print the label, name and paste them here

Comment: Yes but not their values, it's giving 1 row only